# Move record from one data model to another with a button

Tags: google-app-maker

I have two data models, one called `Requested_Allocations` and another called `Approved_Allocations`.

I want to add an `Approve` button to each row of the table displaying the `Requested_Allocations` records. When the user clicks this button, that record is then added to `Approved_Allocations` and removed from `Requested_Allocations`.

I have set up both my data models and have added the `Approve` button to the `Requested_Allocations` table. I imagine that I need to add an `OnClick Event` to the button, but I'm not sure what exactly to do. Any guidance would be great!

Answer (score 0):

It is doable by creating a new record for the `Approved_Allocations` model, copying fields from `Requested_Allocations` into it and removing the source record... but it would too inefficient/complex.

I would strongly recommend to remove one of the models and add 'Status' field for the remaining one. Then you'll be able to query Approved/Requested records with filters:

```js
// querying requested allocations
app.datasources.Allocations.query.filters.Status._equals = 'Requested';
```

and change allocation status with single line of code:

```js
// Approve button click (assuming that it shared datasource with row)
widget.datasource.item.Status = 'Approved';
```

You can find tons of similar code in [Travel Approval](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/templates/travel-approval/) and [Document Approval](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/templates/document-approval/) templates.